# Android layouts:define onClick in XML layout which referes to a method in super class

Tags: android, layout, onclicklistener, clicklistener

I have a button in my activity called `LoginActivity` which is derived from `BaseActivity`. Inside its layout file I have below declaration:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backPressed"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="act"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
```

Build process prompts below error:

```
Corresponding method handler '`public void act(android.view.View)`' not found
```

While it is defined in super class. I want to know how should I reference to `BaseActivity.act(..)` inside layout of `LoginActivity`.

And here is declaration of `BaseActivity.act()`:

```
fun act(view: View) {
        val context = view.context
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.backPressed-> //some stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: Override the method in LoginActivity and just called super(view)..

Comment: @W0rmH0le Thanks for your help. Method in super class is defined as final (not `open`). Is it a good experience to make act method `open` to call only `super.act`?

Comment: When you refrence a method in xml that must be public.

Comment: There's no problem. final is usefull if you don't want to override a method for any case. Since it is your project and you have control over it, there's no problem. Another option would be: create a method act in child class. In parent, you create a final method with different signature: handleAct(). Then, child method (act) call that parent method (handleAct). This is way, you can keep your parent method final.

Comment: @W0rmH0le please put these explanations as an answer

Comment: @Onik posted. please check

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I see two fixes. Also, there are some points you must consider.

**Override act in child class and call parent method**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void act(View view) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void act(View view) {
        super.act(view);
    }
}
```

**Keeping the implementation final**

As you mentioned, your method is final. So, if you want to keep the implementation solely in the BaseActivity, you can do something like:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public final void handleAct(View view) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void act(View view) {
        handleAct(view);
    }
}
```

**Is act common to all activities?**

Another point you can consider is the fact that your base class should implement the methods that are common to all child activities. If `act` is related only to the `LoginActivity`, then, it should not be implemented in the `BaseActivity` but only the in the `LoginActivity`.. Otherwise, any class which extends `BaseActivity` will carry the act method unnecessarily.

**EDIT**
Check the [pankaj-kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550966/pankaj-kumar) comments. Maybe, all you have to do is add `public` to the method signature:

```
public fun act(view: View) {
    ...
}
```